# Setting the variable 'db_table' does not include the app prefix to table names

Tags: django, django-models

When using 'db_table' to explicitly set the database table name, how can you preserve the naming convention of "app_table_name"? The app name is removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know the `db_table` option will get precedence over the existing convention of app name + model name. If you set it explicitly you will have to ***prefix the app name yourself***.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Add the app to the table name yourself.